# The requested PHP extension ext-intl ^1.1 has the wrong version (7.3.17) installed

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, laragon

When I run composer intall, it gives me this error

```
"The requested PHP extension ext-intl ^1.1 has the wrong version (7.3.17) installed. Install or enable PHP's intl extension."
```

I've already unticked the semi-colon in php.ini for extension=intl. I'm using Laragon Full 4.0.16 for my local web server.

This is the composer.json:

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-intl": "^1.1",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
```

This is the composer.lock:

```
"platform": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "ext-intl": "^1.1",
    "ext-mbstring": "*"
},
```

It seems to use the PHP version for the ext-intl. And even though its like that, the condition should still hold true for the requirement.

Using phpinfo() shows:
[image]

I've looked this up and some people would suggest to use "--ignore-platform-reqs" but it doesn't really solve the problem although it is a quick work around. Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Comment: for `ext-something` composer requirements just use `"*"` as the version. I'm not sure composer checks the actual extension version

Comment: @apokryfos Do I change this in both lock and json file?

Comment: Just the .json file. The lock file should get updated automatically on `composer install`